# sending POST request to Controller action works in IE not in Chrome

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Action code is:

```
//tickets is null in chrome but has value in IE
public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeStatus(string tickets)
{
   //Code goes here
}
```

ajax call

```
var selectTickets = '"ticket1","ticket2"'    
$.ajax
     ({
          type: 'post',
          url: "/SkyBusTickets/ChangeStatus/",
          data: {'tickets': selectTickets},
          success: unexpiredTicketsBulkStatusChangeSuccess,
          failure: unexpiredTicketsBulkStatusChangeError
     });
```

In chrome it gives an error in console

> jquery.js:9536 POST http://localhost:54656/SkyBusTickets/ChangeStatus/
>   500 (Internal Server Error)

what needs to be done to make it work in both browsers?

**EDIT**

If I change the action method to the below one it will stop working in IE too

```
   //tickets is null in both chrome & IE
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeStatus([FromBody]string tickets)
    {
       //Code goes here
    }
```

Comment: I'd normally include contentType: "application/json" and dataType: "json" and also tag my controller action with the [HttpPost] attribute and [FromBody] parameter attribute.

Comment: I tried that too. It doesn't work.

Comment: Did you also mark the action as [HttpPost]?

Comment: yes I tried all the things you mentioned but it's not working

Comment: Try: data: JSON.stringify({'tickets': selectTickets}), or data: JSON.stringify(selectTickets)

Comment: Sounds like you are having CORS issues. Is your javascript and your api located on differentports? iirc IE treats that as same domain, Firefox/Chrome treat is as different and you need to allow it via CORS for ajax calls to it

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it worked for me

```
//ajax side 
$(document).ready(function () {
        var selectTickets = '"ticket1","ticket2"'
        $.ajax
             ({
                type: 'post',
                url: "api/Test/ChangeStatus",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { "": selectTickets },
                success: function () {

                },
                failure: function () {

                }
             });
    });
```

In Controller part

```
[HttpPost]
public string ChangeStatus([FromBody]string tickets)
{
    return "sdfdf";
}
```

You can refer this link 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/web-api-with-ajax-understand-formbody-and-formuri-attribute/